# Flexbox - responsive right align UL within div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I am trying to right align a UL within a div. The goal is to have a responsive navbar wherein a change in the size of the div will lead to the UL within it moving in the opposite direction so as not to fall out of view.

However i end up with the following if i narrow area from right to left:

[image]

Ideally should stay like this:

[image]

My css:

```
.navbar {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 2000px;
font: 600 1.25em/1.38 'Josefin Slab';
background-color: rgb(246, 84, 84);
}

.navbar .text {
float: left;
min-height: 39px;
font-size: 1em;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navbar .text-1{
margin-top: 50%;
}

.navbar .text {
clear: both;
width: 31.9157778085%;
flex:1;
margin-left:47%;
}

.navbar .navwrapper{
display:flex;

/*set direction every browser*/
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;

flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.navbar .text:hover{
text-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:600);
```

The HTML:

```
<div className="navbar clearfix">
            <ul className="navwrapper">
                <Link to="/" id="Home" className="text text-1">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/Training" id="Training" className="text text-2">Training</Link>
                <Link to="/Contributions" id="Contribute" className="text text-3">Contribute</Link>
                <Link to="/Info" id="Info" className="text text-4">Info</Link>
                <Link to="/About" id="About" className="text text-5">About</Link>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `display: flexbox` on your **.navbar** parent and `justify-content: flex-end` should right align your wrapper div.

Here's an HTML/CSS example:

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2000px;
  font: 600 1.25em/1.38 'Josefin Slab';
  background-color: rgb(246, 84, 84);
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar .navwrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 50%;

  /* UL Reset */
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar .navwrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .text {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .text:hover{
  text-shadow: 2px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navwrapper">
    <li><a href="/" id="Home" class="text">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Training" id="Training" class="text">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Contributions" id="Contribute" class="text">Contribute</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Info" id="Info" class="text text-4">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="/About" id="About" class="text text-5">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```